# "No EFI System Partition was found" despite it seeming to exist

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I am attempting to reinstall Ubuntu 22.04 after a broken upgrade, on a dual-boot system with Windows 10. Both OSes boot, however while attempting to install Ubuntu I'm given the message that *"No EFI System Partition was found. The system will likely not be able to boot successfully, and the installation process may fail."*

Looking at my partition table, there seems to already be an EFI partition—it's labeled Windows Boot Manager, perhaps that's the issue. Here's the transcription from the Ubuntu install screen

```
/dev/nvme0n1
  free space                             1 MB
  /dev/nvme0n1p1  fat32  /boot/efi     104 MB       35 MB   Windows Boot Manager
  /dev/nvme0n1p2                        16 MB     unknown
  /dev/nvme0n1p3   ntfs             157056 MB   101221 MB
  free space                             1 MB
  /dev/nvme0n1p4   ext4  /boot         524 MB      217 MB
  /dev/nvme0n1p5   ext4  /           74999 MB    28503 MB  [want to install Ubuntu here]
  /dev/nvme0n1p6   ntfs             262783 MB    95200 MB  [shared storage]
  /dev/nvme0n1p7   swap               4095 MB     unknown
  /dev/nvme0n1p8   ntfs                523 MB      430 MB
  free space                             1 MB
```

Should I create another partition EFI partition? Can I delete the old one? Should I just ignore the warning, overwrite the Ubuntu partition, and everything should work?

Comment: What is the flag for your current EFI patition?  My understanding is that the label is not important but the flag is.  Your EFI partition should have a "boot" flag.

Comment: It usually in gparted has esp, boot flags. Also make sure Windows fast start up and bitlocker are off. Those can interfere with Linux NTFS driver from correctly seeing Windows type partitions.You can only have one ESP per device or drive. Some have needed chkdsk or dosfsck. Very few have had to delete ESP & recreate it. But then you have to do Windows repairs to have Windows reinstall its boot files into the ESP.